# GSoC: How can we use SE better for this year edition?

Tags: discussion

We have already a GSoC tag and (most) students are using it, hopefully.

Is it possible and useful to identify the GSoC students (eg a special hat), or ask them to add it to their name, or... The idea would be that knowing they are there to work full time for more than two months, we might be willing to advise them differently

I wonder if it makes sense to use SE to help further the mentors (eg. discussion about mentoring) or to help the students supporting themselves directly too